# Printing the Address of same variable using cout and printf gives different output

Tags: c++

I was trying to print the address of a variable using printf and cout in my .cpp file but both the line gives me different output.

Here is the code

```
#include <bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std ;

int main(){
    int a = 5 ;
    cout << &a << endl ;
    printf("%u\n",&a);
}
```

if the variable is same how can the address be different?

Comment: Who teaches `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`? Throw away that piece of nonsense. [Why should I not `#include <bits/stdc++.h>`?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31816095/why-should-i-not-include-bits-stdc-h)

Comment: *how can the address be different?* - Why do you think they are different?

Comment: `printf("%u\n",&a);` should be `printf("%p\n", (void *)&a);`. Your `%u` is for type `unsigned int`.

Comment: but why should we include (void *)

Comment: @RitikSingh: `(void *)` is a [type cast](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/explicit_cast). According to the C and C++ standard, the `%p` `printf` conversion format specifier requires a `void *` argument, not just any pointer argument. The standards do not require the size or representation of a `void *` to be the same as pointers to other types, but all pointer types (except function pointers) must be convertable to `void *`. However, on most modern platforms, they do have the same size and representation, so the cast to `void *` when using `%p` is not necessary on those platforms.